# How to print a list of integers in 10 columns?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I know this might be extremely simple but I am struggling. I would like to print this list of prime numbers in aligned columns with 10 prime numbers on each row.

My program currently prints all the numbers in one line.

```
prime = []
not_prime = []

for i in range(2,numbers+1):

    if i not in not_prime:
        prime.append(i)

        for x in range(i**2,numbers+1,i):
            not_prime.append(x)

print (*prime, sep=' ')
```

Please help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simplest approach would be to just iterate through `prime` at the end where you have `print (*prime, sep=' ')`.

If you're using **Python 2**:

```
# use `numbers = 100` as an example
numbers = 100

prime = []
not_prime = []

for i in range(2,numbers+1):

    if i not in not_prime:
        prime.append(i)

        for x in range(i**2,numbers+1,i):
            not_prime.append(x)

# `enumerate` gives us a tuple of (index, element) in an iterable
for idx, p in enumerate(prime):

    # "{:3d}" is a format string that is similar to the C-style
    # of %X.YA where `X` denotes the character width, `.Y` denotes
    # how many places to display in a floating point number,
    # and `A` denotes the type of what's being printed. Also note,
    # in Python, you don't need to use the `d` in `:3d`, you can just
    # do `{:3}`, but I've included it for your knowledge.
    #
    # the comma says 'don't add a newline after you print this'
    print "{:3d}".format(p),

    # we'll use `idx + 1` to avoid having to deal with the
    # 0-indexing case (i.e., 0 modulo anything is 0)
    if (idx + 1) % 10 == 0:

        # just print a newline
        print
```

Result:

```
  2   3   5   7  11  13  17  19  23  29
 31  37  41  43  47  53  59  61  67  71
 73  79  83  89  97
```

**Edit:**

If you're using **Python 3**, you'll want to change:

```
print "{:3}".format(p),
```

to

```
print ("{:3}".format(p), end="")
```

and you'll want to change where you're printing the newline to

```
print ()
```

The resulting code is therefore:

```
# use `numbers = 100` as an example
numbers = 100

prime = []
not_prime = []

for i in range(2,numbers+1):

    if i not in not_prime:
        prime.append(i)

        for x in range(i**2,numbers+1,i):
            not_prime.append(x)

# `enumerate` gives us a tuple of (index, element) in an iterable
# `start=1` tells enumerate to use a 1-based indexing rather than
# 0-based.
for idx, p in enumerate(prime, start=1):

    # "{:3d}" is a format string that is similar to the C-style
    # of %X.YA where `X` denotes the character width, `.Y` denotes
    # how many places to display in a floating point number,
    # and `A` denotes the type of what's being printed. Also note,
    # in Python, you don't need to use the `d` in `:3d`, you can just
    # do `{:3}`, but I've included it for your knowledge.
    #
    # the comma says 'don't add a newline after you print this'
    print ("{:3d}".format(p), end="")

    # if it's a multiple of 10, print a newline
    if idx % 10 == 0:

        # just print a newline
        print ()
```

Comment: When I run the program, I get a syntax error for "{:3d}". I'm not sure why. I have tried running it without the d as well.

Comment: What version of Python are you running?

Comment: 3.4.3

Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: @MichaelRecachinas ayyyeeeee